# What locale does DecimalFormat and DateFormat use by default? (why is it different to Locale.getDefault()?)

Tags: java, locale, date-format

When debugging my application, if found that `DecimalFormat` and `DateFormat` are set to use `nl_NL` by default, but the system locale seems to be `en_US`.

I found the first by evaluating:

```
new DecimalFormat().symbols.locale
new SimpleDateFormat().locale
```

And the second:

```
Locale.getDefault()
System.getProperty("user.country")
System.getProperty("user.language")
```

What is happening there?

How can I set those formatters to use a certain locale by default? (I'm writing unit tests and would like to set a specific locale without touching the application code)

Answer (score 1):

As of Java 7, [the default locale comes in two categories](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault(java.util.Locale.Category)): "DISPLAY" and "FORMAT".
Both are initially set according to the environment. They can be found by calling `Locale.getDefault(Category)`.

Besides the system properties mentioned in the question:

```
"user.country"
"user.language"
```

The following can also be present when running the JVM:

```
"user.country.format"
"user.language.format"
"user.country.display"
"user.language.display"
```

The reason for that seems to be that [some OS's allow independent localization settings for displaying text and for formatting dates, numbers and currency](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2011/12/default-locale-changes-in-java-7.html).

Answering my last question, by calling `Locale.setDefault(Locale)` [the default locale will be set for all categories](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Locale.java#Locale.setDefault%28java.util.Locale%29).